# Subset based on both columns and rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I've a R dataframe like this containing prices at different times

```
     product_1  product_2  product_3  product_4  product_5
 t1  10         10         10         0          14
 t2  20         0          50         15         15
 t3  30         0          60         12         12
 t4  40         14         15         5          0
```

What query would give me all the table containing prices at all times for products whose price is 0 at least once after a specific time = t2? Basically a subset of data-frame based on both row and column conditions.

```
     product_2  product_5
 t1  10         14
 t2  0          15
 t3  0          12
 t4  14         0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read data:

```
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
    product_1  product_2  product_3  product_4  product_5
 t1  10         10         10         0          14
 t2  20         0          50         15         15
 t3  30         0          60         12         12
 t4  40         14         15         NA          0")
```

Find index of critical time:

```
which.time <- which(rownames(dd)=="t2")
```

Function to identify columns to keep (could also use `any(na.omit(tail(x,-which.time)==0))`; `na.omit()` is necessary to avoid `NA`s ending up in the logical vector that specifies which columns to keep, which will lead to a slightly obscure `undefined columns selected` error ...

```
keepvar <- function(x) {
    any(na.omit(x[-(1:(which.time-1))])==0)
}
```

Now do the actual selection:

```
dd[sapply(dd,keepvar)]
```

Comment: Ok, I am not sure what's wrong here, but your code works, but as soon as I apply it on my huge table with 1663 rows and 8000 columns, I get this error : "Error in `[.data.frame`(dd, sapply(dd, keepvar)) : undefined columns selected "

Only difference I can see is that I read dataframe as a csv, since R cannot make a table for such large number of values. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused.  What do you mean "I read dataframe as a csv"?  CSV is an external file format.  What function did you use to read the data frame (did you use a function from a package)?  What is `class(your_dataframe)` ?

Comment: I meant I read my csv into a dataframe. Class is data.frame

PS. I can see that which.time contains correct value for my dataset. And the function seems totally fine, but I am lost when it comes to error.

Comment: Can you post `dput()` of the first couple of rows and columns of your data set?

Comment: At this point I'm lost too.  We'll need a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) before we can move forward ...

Comment: do you have `NA` values in your data?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, there are 8000 columns! The mock data I gave here is the exact format of my data except with large number of columns and rows. Btw, some of my columns do contain NA values, though that shouldn't cause this problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, it did work. I'm confused, I had checked if your earlier solution works with NA values by introducing some in the mock example. Nonetheless, thanks a ton!

Comment: If my answer solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is called `df`

```
df[,as.logical(apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(x[as.logical(cumsum(rownames(df)=="t2"))] == 0)))]
   product_2 product_5
t1        10        14
t2         0        15
t3         0        12
t4        14         0
```

Comment: I face the same trouble as I have commented to the solution above yours, even with your approach. I'm totally lost here. Any suggestions?